# Does Kolmogorov 0-1 law apply to every translation invariant event?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, percolation

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d \ge 2$, thought of as an infinite graph.  In percolation theory we consider properties random subgraphs of $\Lambda$. In site percolation $\Lambda^s_p$ every node of $\Lambda$ is included with probability $p$ i.i.d., and we take the induced subgraph on those random nodes.  In bond percolation $\Lambda^b_p$ we take every edge with probability $p$.

An event $E$ is a measurable subset of $\{ 0,1 \}^ {V(\Lambda)}$ or $\{ 0,1 \}^ {E(\Lambda)}$.  We say $E$ is translation invariant if it is invariant under translations of $\Lambda$.

Is it true that such an event must be a tail event, in which case [Kolmogorov's zero-one law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero-one_law) applies?

Comment: yes, the usual argument applies:  Let $\mathcal F_n$ be generated by all nodes within n of the origin,  The translation invariant event can be approximated by something in $\mathcal F_n$, for a suitable n, but also by something in $a + \mathcal F_n$ and for large a they are independent